# Nested dropdown toggle on Bootstrap not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to use this theme: https://colorlib.com/polygon/sufee/index.html

This is the HTML it is using:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="index.html"> <i class="menu-icon fa fa-dashboard"></i>Dashboard </a>
                    </li>
                    <h3 class="menu-title">UI elements</h3><!-- /.menu-title -->
                    <li class="menu-item-has-children dropdown show">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true"> <i class="menu-icon fa fa-laptop"></i>Components</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu children dropdown-menu show">
                            <li><i class="fa fa-puzzle-piece"></i><a href="ui-buttons.html">Buttons</a></li>
                            <li><i class="fa fa-id-badge"></i><a href="ui-badges.html">Badges</a></li>
                            <li><i class="fa fa-bars"></i><a href="ui-tabs.html">Tabs</a></li>
                            <li><i class="fa fa-share-square-o"></i><a href="ui-social-buttons.html">Social Buttons</a></li>
                            <li><i class="fa fa-id-card-o"></i><a href="ui-cards.html">Cards</a></li>
                            <li><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i><a href="ui-alerts.html">Alerts</a></li>
                            <li><i class="fa fa-spinner"></i><a href="ui-progressbar.html">Progress Bars</a></li>
                            <li><i class="fa fa-fire"></i><a href="ui-modals.html">Modals</a></li>
                            <li><i class="fa fa-book"></i><a href="ui-switches.html">Switches</a></li>
                            <li><i class="fa fa-th"></i><a href="ui-grids.html">Grids</a></li>
                            <li><i class="fa fa-file-word-o"></i><a href="ui-typgraphy.html">Typography</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menu-item-has-children dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> <i class="menu-icon fa fa-table"></i>Tables</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu children dropdown-menu">
                            <li><i class="fa fa-table"></i><a href="tables-basic.html">Basic Table</a></li>
                            <li><i class="fa fa-table"></i><a href="tables-data.html">Data Table</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menu-item-has-children dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> <i class="menu-icon fa fa-th"></i>Forms</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu children dropdown-menu">
                            <li><i class="menu-icon fa fa-th"></i><a href="forms-basic.html">Basic Form</a></li>
                            <li><i class="menu-icon fa fa-th"></i><a href="forms-advanced.html">Advanced Form</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <h3 class="menu-title">Icons</h3><!-- /.menu-title -->

                    <li class="menu-item-has-children dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> <i class="menu-icon fa fa-tasks"></i>Icons</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu children dropdown-menu">
                            <li><i class="menu-icon fa fa-fort-awesome"></i><a href="font-fontawesome.html">Font Awesome</a></li>
                            <li><i class="menu-icon ti-themify-logo"></i><a href="font-themify.html">Themefy Icons</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="widgets.html"> <i class="menu-icon ti-email"></i>Widgets </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menu-item-has-children dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> <i class="menu-icon fa fa-bar-chart"></i>Charts</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu children dropdown-menu">
                            <li><i class="menu-icon fa fa-line-chart"></i><a href="charts-chartjs.html">Chart JS</a></li>
                            <li><i class="menu-icon fa fa-area-chart"></i><a href="charts-flot.html">Flot Chart</a></li>
                            <li><i class="menu-icon fa fa-pie-chart"></i><a href="charts-peity.html">Peity Chart</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li class="menu-item-has-children dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> <i class="menu-icon fa fa-area-chart"></i>Maps</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu children dropdown-menu">
                            <li><i class="menu-icon fa fa-map-o"></i><a href="maps-gmap.html">Google Maps</a></li>
                            <li><i class="menu-icon fa fa-street-view"></i><a href="maps-vector.html">Vector Maps</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <h3 class="menu-title">Extras</h3><!-- /.menu-title -->
                    <li class="menu-item-has-children dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> <i class="menu-icon fa fa-glass"></i>Pages</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu children dropdown-menu">
                            <li><i class="menu-icon fa fa-sign-in"></i><a href="page-login.html">Login</a></li>
                            <li><i class="menu-icon fa fa-sign-in"></i><a href="page-register.html">Register</a></li>
                            <li><i class="menu-icon fa fa-paper-plane"></i><a href="pages-forget.html">Forget Pass</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

It is pretty standard. Now I want to add second level of dropdown i.e below Buttons I want to have it's items as Button 1, Button 2, Button 3

so I try to put this HTML there:

```
<li class="menu-item-has-children dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="active" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              <i class="fa fa-puzzle-piece fa-2x"></i> Buttons</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu children dropdown-menu">
              <li>
                <a>Button 1</a>
              </li>
<li>
                <a>Button 2</a>
              </li>
<li>
                <a>Button 3</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
```

Button when I click on Buttons to open up it's dropdown it instead closes the parent. What am I doing wrong?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to solve this issue is to add javascript.

Add this to your js file:

```
$('.menu-item-has-children .menu-item-has-children a').on("click", function(e){
    $(this).next('ul').toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Reference:
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_dropdown_multilevel_css&stacked=h

Comment: Brilliant. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As you have not update any fiddle yet. Watching to your code what I have found wrong is with the `class` attribute which you have mentioned multiple times

```
<a href="#" class="active" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          <i class="fa fa-puzzle-piece fa-2x"></i> Buttons</a>
```

on above code you are using two classes remove `class="active"` and then try Hope it will help